# IEEE Latex Bibliography (remove letter at the end of each reference)

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I'm trying to create a bibliography with Mendeley in Latex for my Thesis, but at the end of the document there is a letter "V", in blue color as a link. I wanted to remove that letter "V" after each reference. How can I do this?

[image]

The code I have created so far is a multi-part compilation, in a final file with a .tex extension:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%oneside ou openany serve para tirar paginas em branco depois das secções
% Omitting Page Numbers
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

% Packages
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4.9cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
%\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{afterpage}  % blank pages
\usepackage{multirow}  % table
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % table
\usepackage{xpatch}  % table
\usepackage{tabu}  % table
\usepackage{hhline}  % cell color does not overlap cell line
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % headers
\usepackage{breakcites}  % references do not go though margins
\usepackage{sectsty}  % change chapter title size
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % four level contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % numbered four level contents
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % math
\usepackage{amsmath}  % math
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}  % references

%\newcommand{\rectangle}{{  % rectangle
%  \ooalign{$\sqsubset\mkern3mu$\cr$\mkern3mu\sqsupset$\cr}
%}}

%\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

% References
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=MidnightBlue,
   filecolor=MidnightBlue,
   citecolor=BrickRed,
   urlcolor=MidnightBlue,
   bookmarksopen=true,
   linktocpage=true,
   pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
   pdfstartpage=1
}

% Blank Page
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage}

% Hide Blank Pages Numbers + Headers
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}

% Space between numbers and text
\geometry{footskip=1.2cm}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\newgeometry{left=3cm, right=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=1.2cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9}

%\include{parts/capa_provisoria}
\include{parts/capa_definitiva}

\afterpage{\blankpage} %comentar para tirar paginas em branco

\endgroup

% Preamble for Thesis
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage  % hide blank pages numbers + headers

\include{parts/agradecimentos}

\include{parts/abstract}

\include{parts/resumo}

%\include{parts/resumo_alargado}

\include{parts/contents}

\include{parts/list_of_figures}

\include{parts/list_of_tables}

\afterpage{\blankpage} %comentar para tirar paginas em branco

% After Introductory Pages
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,headsep=1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 

\chaptertitlefont{\Huge} % to fit chapter title to one line
\chapternumberfont{\Huge} 

\include{parts/introducao}

\include{parts/propriedadesTMDs}

\include{parts/aplicacoes}

\include{parts/metodosexperimentais}

\include{parts/resultadosediscussao}

\include{parts/conclusao}

\pagestyle{plain}  % no more header 

\include{parts/bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

The code corresponding to the bibliography part is as follows (The file containing the bibliography is called Tese.bib.):

```
\newpage
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliografia}
\bibliography{Tese}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

The .bib file obtained with Mendeley is as follows:

```
@article{Trauner2018,
abstract = {This supporting information contains a system description and flowcharts, a full inventory of the battery components, complete numerical values of the battery pack, a sensitivity analysis of the number of cycles, and a structural path analysis related to the study presented in the main article.},
author = {Trauner, Dirk},
file = {:Users/maria/Desktop/ambiente de trabalho 28-05-2019/Engenharia F{\'{i}}sica/Quinto ano/Moodle 2019$\backslash$:2020/estagio/artigos lidos/Fluid Guided CVD Growth for Large-scale Monolayer Two-dimensional Materials - 2020/am0c04125{\_}si{\_}001.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0027-8424},
journal = {Jacs-Si},
keywords = {10550 north torrey pines,and floyd e,ca 92037,cremeens,dawson,department of chemistry,j{\"{o}}rg zimmermann,la jolla,materials and methods,matthew e,philip e,porting information,road,romesberg,the scripps research institute,wayne yu},
number = {1},
pages = {1--5},
title = {{Supporting Information Supporting Information}},
volume = {2},
year = {2018}
}
@article{Sial2018,
abstract = {Controllable atmospheric pressure CVD has been optimized to grow transition metal dichalcogenide MoSe2 with tunable morphology at 750 °C on a silicon substrate with a native oxide layer of 250 nm. Utilizing tetrapotassium perylene-3,4,9,10-tetracarboxylate (PTAS) as a seed promoter and varying the vertical distance between the substrate and the precursor MoO3, different morphologies of MoSe2 were achieved, including 2D triangles, hexagons, 3D pyramids and vertically aligned MoSe2 sheets. We find that the shape of MoSe2 is highly dependent upon the distance h between the substrate and the precursor. The change in the morphology is attributed to the confinement of vapor (MoO3 and Se) precursors and their concentrations due to the change in h. These results are helpful in improving our understanding about the factors which influence the morphology (shape evolution) and also the continuous growth of MoSe2 films.},
author = {Sial, M. Naeem and Usman, Muhammad and Zheng, Binjie and Yu, Yanan and Mavri{\v{c}}, Andra{\v{z}} and Qing, Fangzhu and Valant, Matjaz and Wang, Zhiming M.},
doi = {10.1039/c8ce00917a},
file = {:Users/maria/Desktop/ambiente de trabalho 28-05-2019/Engenharia F{\'{i}}sica/Quinto ano/Moodle 2019$\backslash$:2020/estagio/artigos lidos/Controlled synthesis of highly crystalline CVD-derived monolayer MoSe2 and shape evolution mechanism - 2018/CVD growth of molybdenum diselenide surface structures with tailored morphology suplemento - 2018.pdf.pdf:pdf},
issn = {14668033},
journal = {CrystEngComm},
number = {33},
pages = {4867--4874},
title = {{CVD growth of molybdenum diselenide surface structures with tailored morphology}},
volume = {20},
year = {2018}
}
```

Comment: Maybe don't load `hyperref` with the `pagebackref` option?

Comment: @Mico If I do that it gives me an error at the bottom of the ```\hypersetup```. If I comment on the ```\hypersetup``` part it will still give me an error.

Comment: @Mico I finally got it! I just removed the ```pagebackref``` as you suggested. By the way, what is the ```pagebackref``` used for, out of curiosity?

Comment: Quoting the user guide of the `hyperref` package: "`pagebackref` adds ‘backlink’ text to the end of each item in the bibliography, as a list of page numbers."

Comment: @Mico I didn't know that command. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @Mico If you want you can put the comment as an answer to close the question and I give you an OK in the answer for the recognition of the help you gave as a form of gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(re-posting an earlier comment, so that this query can be considered to have received a formal answer)

The undesired Roman numerals are generated as a consequence of the instruction

```
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

Quoting from the user guide of the `hyperref` package:

> `pagebackref` adds ‘backlink’ text to the end of each item in the bibliography, as a list of page numbers.

Deleting the `pagebackref` option will tell `hyperref` to cease creating the unwanted backlinks.